# Firebase Reading Data Error onDataChange method on null object reference

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I'm facing an error while reading data from firebase DB, I'm trying to allow login with MAC address :

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Data:

[image: Data Image]

This is my code :

```
 DatabaseReference users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Query query = users.orderByChild("macAddress").equalTo(getMacAddr());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            if(!(user.getEmail().equals(edtEmail.getText().toString()))){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please Login With Phone You Registered With", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                waitingdialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please Login With Phone You Registered With", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            waitingdialog.dismiss();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

getMacAddr() is a function that returns mac address of the device in a string

User.class code used in above code  :

```
public class User {

private  String email,password,name,phone,macAddress;
private int isSecured;

public User(String email, String name, String password,String phone,String macAddress,int isSecured){

    this.email=email;
    this.name=name;
    this.password=password;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.macAddress=macAddress;
    this.isSecured=isSecured;
}
public User() {}

public int getIsSecured() {
    return isSecured;
}

public void setIsSecured(int isSecured) {
    this.isSecured = isSecured;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMacAddress() {
    return macAddress;
}

public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
    this.macAddress = macAddress;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

this is User.class that is used to create user object

Comment: Please provide your User.class code too

Comment: @JagarYousef Done

Comment: Try to include an if statement `if(user.getEmail() != null)` but sometimes this null exception happens in Firebase when there is unlogical code somewhere, unfortunately, I did not see it in your code.

Comment: Just for fun - in your null constructor in User set the "email" field to "I am never set" and add the email to your snackbar message.  Seems likely you're not getting an email field back.

Comment: Is this a typo: `edtEmail.getText()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the error , i changed this line :

```
Query query = users.orderByChild("macAddress").equalTo(getMacAddr());
```

to

```
Query query=users.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderByChild("email");
```

auth is FirebaseAuth object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the issue is indeed within the code that you have provided and given the error message

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

I would think that the problem is on this line:

```
Query query = users.orderByChild("macAddress").equalTo(getMacAddr());
```

More specifically, it appears that `users.orderByChild("macAddress")` is returning `null`. I would look into how the `users` entry is defined in the Firebase database and make sure it is structured correctly. Maybe you can try placing a breakpoint on the problem line and examine the `users` object to verify that `users.orderByChild("macAddress")` is not returning `null` and make corrections to the Firebase db as needed.

Comment: `orderByChild` is merely part of Firebase's query builder. It never returns `null`. It seems much more like that `user.getEmail()` returns `null`, i.e. `user.getEmail().equals(...`